# git: Your branch is ahead by X commits

Tags: git, git-commit

How does this actually come about?

I am working in one repo by myself at the moment, so this is my workflow:

1. Change files
2. Commit
3. Repeat 1-2 until satisfied
4. Push to master

Then when I do a `git status` it tells me that my branch is *ahead by X commits* (presumably the same number of commits that I have made). Is it because when you push the code it doesn't actually update your locally cached files (in the .git folders)? `git pull` seems to 'fix' this strange message, but I am still curious why it happens, maybe I am using git wrong?

---

> including what branch is printed in the message

My local branch is ahead of master

> where do you push/pull the current branch

I am pushing to GitHub and pulling to whichever computer I happen to be working on at that point in time, my local copy is always fully up to date as I am the only one working on it.

> it doesn't actually check the remote repo

That is what I thought, I figured that I would make sure my understanding of it was correct.

> are you passing some extra arguments to it?

Not ones that I can see, maybe there is some funny config going on on my end?

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: How are you doing the `push` and what are your remote and branch config settings?

Comment: it doesn't actually check the remote repo, you need to do a git fetch the fetch the latest information on the remote repo after performing the push, this will update the local "remote" branch that it uses to track against.

Comment: @Sekhat: While `git status` doesn't check the remote repository, `git pull` does. If you have a tracking branch for a repository that you push to, `git push` will update your local tracking branch to reflect the new state of the remote branch if your push is successful. This is why I asked about the asker's config because if it is not happening correctly there is probably a configuration error.

Comment: `git status`? really? my `git status` never tells me how far ahead my branch is .. are you passing some extra arguments to it?

Comment: @hasen j: `git status` doesn't go to the remote repository to check whether the remote branch has been updated. It tells you how far ahead your local branch is compared to your _locally stored_ remote tracking branch. The issue is that a normal `git push` (as well as fetch and pull) should update the remote tracking branch and for the the asker this doesn't appear to be working. To see why we need to see both the exact form of `git push` that is being used and the local repository's config but as the asker has already accepted an answer I can't see this happening now.

Answer (score 538, accepted):

If you get this message after doing a `git pull remote branch`, try following it up with a `git fetch`. (Optionally, run `git fetch -p` to prune deleted branches from the repo)

Fetch seems to update the local representation of the remote branch, which doesn't necessarily happen when you do a `git pull remote branch`.

Comment: Bravo. That was really the issue. I started by creating a repository on google code. Then I cloned this repository on my laptop and I do work there and push the changes, laptop => code.google. I used to get this message on my server where I had created a clone of code.google code repository and I used to pull the changes. I think fetch is required to update the local database.

Comment: We had the same problem here because another branch (A) pointed to the same commitid of master. Pulling A and then pulling master resulted on this same situation.
When git pulled A, the commitid was updated to last one, so pulling master it has nothing to actually pull, so git didn't update the master last commitid and was warning about being "ahead of master".

Comment: I received the message after a `git push origin master`. Neither `git pull` nor `git fetch` followed by the same commit and push command resolved the problem. I had to force a commit instead using `git push --force origin master`.

Comment: Note that this also occurred to me after creating a local branch from a previous tag.  It didn't seem to impact any functionality, but messed up my history graph in source tree.

Comment: @HertzelGuinness But - how do you know it's a bug? Is there a ticket about it somewhere?

Comment: Thank, though I did notice one strange thing. "git fetch origin master" does not help, but "git fetch origin" does. I am on the master branch, so not sure how "git fetch origin" would do something different in the context.

Comment: @Parag see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350876/what-is-the-difference-between-these-git-fetch-syntaxes for an explanation of the differences between those two commands, and how perhaps to modify config file to change the behavior so git fetch remote branch also updates the remote-tracking-branch ref, so git_status does not report 'ahead by'.

Comment: @Parag, also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365415/pull-only-repos-git-status-saying-the-branch-is-ahead-of-origin-master-why/7365922#comment43028967_7365922 answer discusses the details of ORIG_HEAD and FETCH_HEAD going out of sync, causing the status warning, and possible config file corrections.

Comment: Clarifying this: `Fetch seems to update the local representation of the remote branch, which doesn't necessarily happen when you do a git pull remote branch.`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch/15990759#15990759

Answer (score 218):

Use

```
git pull --rebase
```

The --rebase option means that git will move your local commit aside, synchronise with the remote and then try to apply your commits from the new state.

Comment: A really good way to prevent useless merges and have a cleaner tree in origin!

Comment: I tried this command, but I still have the same issue...`$ git pull --rebase
Current branch xyz is up to date.

$ git status
On branch xyz
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/xyz' by 6 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: This answer is wrong: If you use it without understanding the situation, you are potentially producing trouble for times ahead (rewritten history!). If you understand the situation, this will *not* be the fix for it. Please think before you type when using `git`, and don't ever mindlessly rewrite history!

Comment: What is the diff to the answer of @Rich?

Answer (score 166):

### Use these 3 simple commands

**Step 1** : `git checkout <branch_name>`

**Step 2**  : `git pull -s recursive -X theirs`

**Step 3**  : `git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>`

More details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39698570/2439715

Enjoy.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually fixed the issue for me. Commands above strangely knocked it down from 12 to 7 commits and this finally removed those

Comment: I concur about this being the only thing that worked for me. I'm convinced GIT has multiple personality disorder sometimes.

Comment: Like @leuan, nothing but `git reset --hard origin/master` cleared it up for me.

Comment: Same here, this is the only steps that worked for me

Comment: This worked for me, specially Step 3 made the change. Thanks!

Answer (score 64):

This worked for me

`git reset --hard origin/master`

The output must look like

`On branch dev
HEAD is now at ae1xc41z Last commit message`

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I was using ```git reset --hard origin master``` but I stil had a commit ready to be pushed

Comment: git reset --hard origin/qa.  this works for me to get sync with remote

Answer (score 54):

I think you’re misreading the message — your branch isn’t ahead of `master`, it *is* `master`. It’s ahead of `origin/master`, which is a **remote tracking branch** that records the status of the remote repository from your last `push`, `pull`, or `fetch`. It’s telling you exactly what you did; you got ahead of the remote and it’s reminding you to push.

Comment: This is actually after I pushed. I had to pull (or possibly fetch?) to get it to not have that message.

Answer (score 28):

I had this issue on my stage server where I do only pulls.
And hard reset helped me to clean HEAD to the same as remote.

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

So now I have again:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

Comment: I first tried without the --hard flag and it worked!

Answer (score 26):

Someone said you might be misreading your message, you aren't. This issue actually has to do with your `<project>/.git/config` file. In it will be a section similar to this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

If you remove the fetch line from your project's .git/config file you'll stop the "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by `N` commits." annoyance from occurring.

Or so I hope. :)

Comment: I shall check that out next time I see the `ahead by x commits` message. I haven't seen the message in a while.

Comment: I haven't seen the message in a while. I think it is because I have started creating the git repo locally, then pushing it to a remote repo instead of the other way around...

Comment: I tried this, but it made eGit in Eclipse start popping up with "internal error" when I tried to commit. Git itself seemed to work fine, though.

Comment: What does that line do? and what am I missing out on by removing it? (apart from the annoyance)

Comment: This fixed my problem too, but why? (git pull didn't fix the issue)

Comment: This worked, but it's more like suppressing the error. Add the line back and you will start getting warning again.

Comment: This is incorrect. It just suppresses the message, **regardless** of being ahead of origin/master or **not**. I am yet not sure what the right solution is.

Answer (score 22):

**Note: this particular *question* is, at the time I write this answer, quite old.  It was posted three years before the first release of a version of Git that fixed many of these problems.**  It seems worth adding a modern answer along with explainers, though.  [The existing accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323933/1256452) suggests running `git fetch -p`,<sup>1</sup> which is a good idea, although less-often *required* these days.  It was much more necessary before Git version 1.8.2 came out; that Git was released three years after the original question.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `-p` or `--prune` option is not required and is suggested only parenthetically in the linked answer.  See the longer sections below for what it does.

---

## How does this actually come about?

The original question asks:

> How does this actually come about?

The *this* in question is the fact that after `git push origin master`, the OP runs `git status` and sees the message `On branch master` followed by `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.`  To properly answer the question, we need to break it up into pieces.

#### First, each (local) branch has an *upstream* setting

This claim is actually just a bit too strong.  Each of your own local branches, in your own Git repository, *can* have *one* setting that Git calls an *upstream*.  Or, that branch can have *no* upstream.  Old versions of Git were not very consistent about calling this an *upstream* setting, but in modern Git, it's more consistent.  We also have `git branch --set-upstream-to` and `git branch --unset-upstream` for setting, or clearing, an upstream.

These `--set-upstream-to` and `--unset-upstream` affect the *current branch*.  The current branch is the one you are `on`, when `git status` says `on branch xyzzy` or whatever it is it says.  You *choose* this branch with `git checkout` or—since Git 2.23—`git switch`.<sup>2</sup>  Whatever branch you checked out, that's the one you're on.<sup>3</sup>

If you use `--unset-upstream`, this *removes* the current branch's upstream.  With no upstream, this stops the message about being ahead or behind or diverged.  But this message is meant to be useful, so you probably shouldn't just remove the upstream as a way to make it stop happening.  (Do feel free to *ignore* the message—it's not a *error* after all—if you don't find it useful.)

If you run `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/xyzzy`, that sets the current branch's upstream to `origin/xyzzy`.  For a branch named `xyzzy`, this would be the typical correct setting.  Some acts of creating branches *automatically* set the (typically-correct) upstream, and some don't, so if you used a branch-creating operation that set the right upstream automatically, you need not do anything.  If you want a different upstream, or if you used a branch-creating operation that set *no* upstream, you can use this to change the upstream.

The things you can set an upstream to are:

- another of your own (local) branches: `git branch --set-upstream-to=experiment` makes your own local `experiment` the upstream of the current branch; or
- any of your *remote-tracking names*, such as `origin/main` or `origin/master` or `origin/xyzzy`.  These are the names output by `git branch -r`.  Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names* (I like to drop the word "branch" here), and we'll talk about them more in a moment.

**The ahead, behind, up-to-date, or diverged message that `git status` prints is derived from running the somewhat magic-looking command:**

```
git rev-list --count --left-right $branch...$upstream
```

where `$branch` is the current *branch* name, and `$upstream` is the string from its upstream setting (from `git branch --set-upstream-to` above).  There are three dots between the two names here, and the `--count`, `--left-right`, and three dots are all required to get `git rev-list` to spit out the two numbers.

---

<sup>2</sup>If you have Git 2.23 or later, it's a good idea to move to `git switch` because it avoids some tricky `git checkout` behaviors that have historically led beginners into trouble (and occasionally even tripped up Git experts).  However, if you are used to `git checkout`, you can keep using it as long as you like, as it's still supported.  The real problem is basically that `git checkout` was overly powerful and could destroy work unexpectedly.  The new `git switch` is deliberately less-powerful and won't do that; the "destroy my work on purpose" operations were moved into `git restore`.

<sup>3</sup>It's possible to be on *no* branch, in what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode.  If you use `git checkout` it can put you in this mode suddenly (though it prints a big scary warning, so if you don't see the scary warning, it didn't do that), but if you use `git switch`, you must *allow* detached-HEAD mode with `git switch --detach`.  There's nothing *wrong* with this mode, you just need to be careful once you're in it, not to lose any new commits you make.  It's easy to lose them if you're not careful.  In normal mode, Git won't lose new commits like this.

If you're in detached HEAD mode, you have no upstream—by definition, because you have no branch—and none of the stuff in this question applies.

---

#### Reachability

This part is a bit technical and I will outsource much of it to a web site, [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  I will summarize it here though like this: *branch names* (like `main` or `xyzzy`) and *remote-tracking names* (`origin/main`, `origin/xyzzy`) are how Git *finds* commits.  Git is all about the *commits*.  Your branch names only matter for *finding* your commits.  Of course, if you can't find them, you're in trouble, so your branch names do matter.  But the key is *reachability*, which is the technical term.

Each commit in a Git repository is numbered, with a big ugly [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) string of letters and digits.  This is the commit's *hash ID* and it's how Git *really* finds the commit.

Each commit contains two things: a full snapshot of every source file (in a special, compressed, Git-ified, and de-duplicated form), and some information about the commit itself: *metadata* telling who made it, when, and why (their log message), for instance.  In the metadata, each commit holds the commit number(s) of some earlier commit(s).  This means that one commit can find another—earlier—commit.

As [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) notes, this is a bit like a railway train.  It's great once you're *on* the train, which in this case will take you backwards, automatically, to all the earlier train stops.  But first you have to find your way *to* a train station.  A Git branch name will do that: it holds the hash ID of the *latest* commit on your branch.

We can draw that like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch
```

The branch name `branch` holds the hash ID of the *latest* commit.  We say that the name *points to* the commit.  Whatever big ugly hash ID that really is, we've just used the letter `H` to stand in for it here.

`H` is an actual commit, so it has a saved snapshot—your files—and some metadata.  In the metadata, Git saved the hash ID of an *earlier* commit.  We'll call that earlier commit `G`.  We say that `H` *points to* `G`.  Git can find `H` by the branch name pointer, and that gives Git access to the commit, including the metadata, so now Git has the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.

`G` is of course also an actual commit: it has a saved snapshot and some metadata.  In the metadata for `G`, Git saved the hash ID of an earlier commit `F`.  We say that `G` points to `F`, and now Git can find `F` using this saved hash ID.

This repeats forever, or rather, until we get to the very first commit ever.  That commit (presumably we'd call it `A` here) *doesn't* point backwards to an earlier commit, because there is no earlier commit.

This concept of *reachability* is basically a summary of what happens if we start at commit `H`, as found by branch name `branch`, and work backwards.  We reach commit `H`, which reaches backwards to commit `G`, which reaches back to `F`, and so on.

#### Branch names and remote-tracking names

As we just noted, a *branch name* holds the raw hash ID of some commit.  That lets Git *find* that commit.  There's one other special feature about a *branch* name though.

When you use `git checkout` or `git switch` to get *on* a branch, and then make a *new* commit, Git *automatically updates the branch name's stored hash ID*.  That is, suppose we have a series of commits like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- xyzzy (HEAD)
```

We're "on" branch `xyzzy`, which I like to denote by attaching the special name `HEAD` to it.  This is useful when there's more than one branch name in the diagram.  Note that `H` is, at the moment, the *newest* commit.  But now we'll make another one, in the usual way.

This new commit gets a new, unique, big ugly hexadecimal hash ID, just like any commit.  Git makes sure that the new commit points backwards to commit `H`, since that's the commit we used to *make* the new commit.  We'll use the letter `I` to represent this new commit.  Let's draw it in:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- xyzzy (HEAD)
            \
             I
```

This picture is actually mid-commit: Git has made `I`, but isn't done with the `git commit` action yet.  Ask yourself this question: how will we *find* commit `I` later?  We're going to need it's hash ID.  Where can we store a hash ID?

If you said: *in a branch name*, you're right.  In fact, the right branch name—as far as Git is concerned, anyway—is the one you're "on" right now.  That's the one we've attached `HEAD` to in this drawing.  So now, as the last part of `git commit`, Git writes `I`'s hash ID into the name `xyzzy`.  This makes it point to commit `I`, like so:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- xyzzy (HEAD)
```

and now there's no reason for the kink in the drawing, so we can straighten it out:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- xyzzy (HEAD)
```

That's how branch names work.  It's really pretty simple, in the end: it just requires getting your head around several things at once.  The name finds the commit.  It finds the *latest* commit.  From there, Git works *backwards* because each commit finds an *earlier* commit.

What about the remote-tracking names?  Well, the trick here is that your Git talks to some other Git.  **Each Git has *its own* branch names.**  You have *your* `master` or `main`; they have *theirs*.  You have *your* `xyzzy` branch and they can have theirs too.

Your Git *could* call up their Git, all the time, every time, and ask them about their branch names.  That's not very efficient, though, and does not work if you are cut off from the Internet.<sup>4</sup>  In any case, Git doesn't do that.  Instead, when your Git calls up their Git and gets a list—from them—of all of their branch names and their hash IDs, *your* Git takes those names and hash IDs and stores them in *your* repository.  This happens when you run `git fetch`.<sup>5</sup>

There's a problem though.  Their `main` or `master`, or their `xyzzy` if they have one, doesn't necessarily mean the *same* commit as *your* `main` or `master` or `xyzzy`.  The solution is simple though: Git just takes their *branch* name and turns it into your *remote-tracking name*.

If `origin`'s `main` or `master` or `xyzzy` has moved, you simply run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`, perhaps with `--prune`.  Your Git calls up their Git.  They list out their branch names and commit hash IDs.  Your Git gets any new commits from them, if necessary: commits they have, that you don't.  Then your Git turns their *branch* names into your *remote-tracking* names and creates or updates your remote-tracking names to remember where *their* branch names pointed, at the moment you ran this `git fetch`.

If you use `--prune`, this handles the case where they *deleted* some branch name(s).  Let's say they had a branch named `oldstuff`.  You got it earlier so you have `origin/oldstuff` in your remote-tracking names.  Then they *deleted* `oldstuff`, so this time they ... just don't have it any more.  Without `--prune`, your Git ignores this.  You keep your old `origin/oldstuff` even though it's dead now.  *With* `--prune`, your Git says: *Oh, huh, this looks dead now* and prunes it away: a remote-tracking name in *your* Git that doesn't correspond to one of their *branch* names, just gets deleted.

The prune option probably should have always been the default, but it wasn't and hence now can't be.<sup>6</sup>  You can, however, configure `fetch.prune` to `true` and *make* it *your* default.

---

<sup>4</sup>That's less common now in 2021 than it was back in 2010.  It was substantially more common in 2005 when Git was first released.  It used to be the case that, say, on an airline flight to a Linux conference, you couldn't get *any* access to the Internet, for any price.

<sup>5</sup>The choice of which names to take, and when to take them, is actually part of the answer here.  It has changed over time in Git—and is still changing a little bit—although there are still various constraints.  We won't go into all the details though.

<sup>6</sup>Git generally takes backwards-compatibility pretty seriously.  It took the 1.x to 2.0 changeover to change the `push.default` default setting from `matching` to `simple`, for instance.

---

#### How `git rev-list` gets the two numbers

Earlier, I noted that the ahead, behind, up-to-date, or diverged message that `git status` prints is derived from running:

```
git rev-list --count --left-right $branch...$upstream
```

What `git rev-list` does here is *count reachable commits*.  The three-dot syntax, described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), produces what in set theory is called a *symmetric difference*.  In non-math-jargon, though, we can just think about this as doing two commit reachability tests,
which we can draw like this:

```
          I--J   <-- xyzzy (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K   <-- origin/xyzzy
```

Here, commit `J` is reachable from your branch name `xyzzy`, because the name points there.  Commit `I` is reachable from commit `J`, so it counts as well.  This leads back to commit `H`—which as you can see from the graph, is a little special.

At the same time, commit `K` is reachable from your remote-tracking name `origin/xyzzy`.  Commit `H` is reachable from `K`.  From commit `H` on back, commits `G` and `F` and so on are all also reachable.  But the two "railroad tracks" *join up* at commit `H`: commit `H` and all earlier commits are reachable from *both names*.

This makes commits `I-J` special in that they're reachable *only from the name `xyzzy`, and `K` special in that it's reachable *only from the name `origin/xyzzy`.  The three-dot notation finds these commits: the ones reachable only from one name, or only from the other.

If we put the branch name on the left, and its upstream on the right, and use the three-dot notation, we'll find all three of these commits for this case.  Using `--count` makes `git rev-list` print this number: 3.  Using `--left-right` tells `git rev-list` to be smarter, though: it should count how many commits are being counted because of the *left* name—the *current branch* name—and how many commits are being counted because of the *right* one, the upstream.  So with both options—and the three dots—we get:

```
2       1
```

as the output, telling us that there are two commits on `xyzzy` that aren't on `origin/xyzzy`, and one commit that's on `origin/xyzzy` that is not on `xyzzy`.  These are commits `J`-and-`I` (on `xyzzy`) and `K` (on `origin/xyzzy`) respectively.

Without the `--count` option, `git rev-list` would list out the hash IDs, prefixed with `<` (left) or `>` (right) symbols.  Using `git log` instead of `git rev-list`, as in:

```
git log --left-right xyzzy...origin/xyzzy
```

(again note the three dots: see [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) and search for Symmetric Difference) we'll get the three commits shown, again prefixed with `<` or `>` as appropriate.

**This is an easy way to see which commits are on your branch, and which commits are on the upstream.**  It's usually more useful with `--decorate`, `--oneline`, and `--graph` (and you might want to add `--boundary` as well in some cases).

#### Ahead, behind, diverged, or up-to-date

So, suppose we have run:

```
git rev-list --count --left-right $branch...$upstream
```

(or—see [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) again—using `$branch@{upstream}` on the right here) and gotten our two counts.  These can be:

- `0` and `0`: Our branch name and our remote-tracking name (or whatever is in the upstream) point to the *same* commit.  Nobody is ahead or behind.  The `git status` command will say `Your branch is up to date with '<upstream>'`.
- nonzero, zero: There are commits on the *current branch* that are not on the upstream.  There are no commits on the upstream that are not on the current branch.  So our branch is *ahead of* the upstream.
- zero, nonzero: There are no commits on the *current branch* that are not on the upstream, but there are some on the upstream that are not on the current branch.  This means our branch is *behind* the upstream.
- nonzero, nonzero: This is like the diagram I drew above.  Both the current branch and its upstream are simultaneously ahead-and-behind each other.  The `git status` command will use the word `diverged`.

We're about to jump back to the original question now.  Let's assume the upstrema of the current branch is a remote-tracking name.  **Note that the counts that `git rev-list` got are based on what is in our remote-tracking branch names.**

#### How does this actually come about?

In the OP's scenario, only one person is making new commits and sending them off with `git push`.  If I am the one person, I might `git clone` something from GitHub, then make a new commit or two and `git push origin master`.

**In modern Git, `git status` would tell me that I am up to date.  In very old Git versions, `git status` would now tell me that my `master` is *ahead of* `origin/master`.**  The reason why is simple: in the old days, `git push` *failed to update `origin/master`*.  Running `git fetch origin`, or just `git fetch`, made your own Git call up the Git over at GitHub, read their information, and realize that your `git push` had worked.

When you run `git push`, you have your Git call up some other Git.  Your Git then offers the other Git any new commits you have, that they don't, that they'll need to complete the `git push`.  They take those commits and put them somewhere.<sup>7</sup>  Then your Git asks their Git—politely asks, by default—if they would, please, if it's OK, set *their* **branch** name to refer to the latest commit, by its hash ID, as seen in *your* branch name.  There's no remote-tracking stuff going on here.  You are just asking them to set the *same name* you're using.

As a general rule, this kind of polite request succeeds if you're just adding new commits to their repository.  It fails if you're asking them to "lose" some commits: you'll get a complaint about this being a "non-fast-forward".  If you're the only one *sending* them new commits, they should never have anything to lose this way, so this should always work.<sup>8</sup>

If the push *fails*, it's appropriate for your Git to leave your remote-tracking name unchanged.  Your Git never got the information from their Git that would let your Git update it.  But if the push *succeeds* ... well, they just set their *branch* name to the hash ID that your Git asked them to use.  So now your Git knows where their branch name points.  Your Git should update your remote-tracking name.

In old Git versions, your Git just *didn't bother doing this*.  In Git version 1.8.2, the Git authors finally fixed this: a successful `git push` has your Git update your remote-tracking name, based on the fact that their Git agreed to the update your Git provided.  So this sort of thing doesn't happen so much any more.

---

<sup>7</sup>In the bad old days, they put them straight into their repository.  In modern Git, they put them in a quarantine area, and only migrate them into their repository if they actually accept the new commits.

<sup>8</sup>Of course, places like GitHub also offer features like *protected branches*, which just say no to *every* push, for instance.  We can also invent fancier scenarios, such as when you have multiple computers and forget that you made and pushed new commits via Computer A, and now try to push from Computer B.

---

#### What if you're not the only one doing `git push`

Suppose that both Alice and Bob have cloned some GitHub repository.  The development in this repository happens on branch `dev` (for develop).  So Alice makes her own `dev` from her `origin/dev`:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD), origin/dev  [Alice's computer]
```

Bob, likewise, makes *his* own `dev`:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD), origin/dev  [Bob's computer]
```

The GitHub repository `dev` ends at `H` too.  (They have no `origin/dev`: the GitHub repository does not bother with remote-tracking names.)

Alice makes a new commit, which we'll call `I`, and draw like this on Alice's computer:

```
          I   <-- dev (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- origin/dev
```

Meanwhile, Bob makes a new commit, which we'll call `J`:

```
...--G--H   <-- origin/dev
         \
          J   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

Now both Alice and Bob try to `git push origin dev`.  One of them gets there first—perhaps Alice:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- dev  [GitHub's systems]
```

Bob sends commit `J`, which to GitHub, looks like this:

```
          I   <-- dev
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J   ... polite request to set dev to J
```

If GitHub would do that, this would "lose" Alice's commit `I`, because Git *finds* commits by starting from the names and working backwards.  So they reject the push with the "not a fast forward" complaint.

Bob now needs to yank commit `I` from GitHub into Bob's own repository, so that *Bob* sees:

```
          I   <-- origin/dev
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J   <-- dev (HEAD)  [Bob's computer]
```

Bob should do this with `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`, perhaps with `--prune` (or with `fetch.prune` set to `true`).  *Now* when Bob runs `git status`, he will get the "diverged" message.

It's now up to Bob, as the loser of the push race, to figure out how to combine *his* work (commit `J`) with Alice's (commit `I`).  There are different ways to combine work.  The two primary ones are `git merge` and `git rebase`.  We won't address who should do what, when, and why here, just the fact that this is another way you might run into "diverged" status when you thought you were strictly ahead of some other Git.

Answer (score 12):

In my case it was because I switched to master using

```
 git checkout -B master
```

Just to pull the new version of it instead of

```
 git checkout master
```

The first command [resets the head of master](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) to my latest commits

I used

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

To fix that

Answer (score 11):

I went through every solution on this page, and fortunately @anatolii-pazhyn commented because his solution was the one that worked. Unfortunately I don't have enough *reputation* to upvote him, but I recommend trying his solution first:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Which gave me:

```
HEAD is now at 900000b Comment from my last git commit here
```

I also recommend:

```
git rev-list origin..HEAD
# to see if the local repository is ahead, push needed

git rev-list HEAD..origin
# to see if the local repository is behind, pull needed
```

You can also use:

```
git rev-list --count --left-right origin/master...HEAD
# if you have numbers for both, then the two repositories have diverged
```

Best of luck

Comment: Be aware! `reset --hard origin/master` will destroy your local commits (the ones you haven't pushed yet)!

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem on a Windows machine. When I ran a `git pull origin master` command, I would get the "ahead of 'origin/master' by X commits" warning. I found that if I instead ran `git pull origin` and did NOT specify the branch, then I would no longer receive the warning.

Comment: I believe this effectively does `git fetch` behind the scenes.

Comment: "git fetch" didn't solved my problem, this did. I got list of newly added branches and this message "You asked to pull from the remote 'upstream', but did not specify a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line." and next "git status" command didn't showed the warning.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to reiterate the same as mentioned by @Marian Zburlia above. It worked for me and would suggest the same to others.

`git pull origin develop`

should be followed by `$ git pull --rebase`.

This will remove the comments coming up on the `$ git status` after the latest pull.

Answer (score 3):

`git fetch` will resolve this for you

If my understanding is correct, your local (cached) `origin/master` is out of date. This command will update the repository state from the server.

Comment: Please add some description

Answer (score 2):

I actually had this happening when I was doing a switch/checkout with TortiseGIT.

My problem was that I had created the branch based on another local branch. It created a "merge" entry in `/.git/config` that looked something like this:

```
[branch "web"]
    merge = refs/heads/develop
    remote = gitserver
```

Where whenever I switched to the "web" branch, it was telling me I was 100+ commits ahead of develop. Well, I was no longer committing to develop so that was true. I was able to simply remove this entry and it seems to be functioning as expected. It is properly tracking with the remote ref instead of complaining about being behind the develop branch.

As Vikram said, this Stack Overflow thread is the top result in Google when searching for this problem so I thought I'd share my situation and solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Then when I do a git status it tells me that my branch is ahead by X commits (presumably the same number of *commits that I have made*).

My experience is in a team environment with many branches. We work in our own feature branches (in local clones) and it was one of those that `git status` showed I was 11 commits ahead. My working assumption, like the question's author, was that +11 was from *commits of my own*.

It turned out that I had pulled in changes from the common `develop` branch into my feature branch many weeks earlier -- but forgot! When I revisited my local feature branch today and did a `git pull origin develop` the number jumped to +41 commits ahead. Much work had been done in `develop` and so my local feature branch was even further ahead of the feature branch on the `origin` repository.

So, if you get this message, think back to any pulls/merges you might have done from other branches (of your own, or others) you have access to. The message just signals you need to `git push` those `pull`ed changes back to the `origin` repo ('tracking branch') from your local repo to get things sync'd up.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the following which is related to the actual question `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/testing/KB-200' by 17 commits`

**Reason**: I created PR for review the last week and then I closed the project. Then today, I opened up the project to make a slight change in the same branch `(testing/KB-200)` and I ran `git pull` first. This pull contained 18 new commits by other developers working on the project this made my local branch ahead of my remote branch by those commits and therefore I was getting that message. So I just had to run the following command:

```
git push origin testing/KB-200
```

and then it was all sync and up to date. `[On branch testing/KB-200 Your branch is up to date with 'origin/testing/KB-200']`

Answer (score 1):

It just reminds you the differences between the current branch and the branch which does the current track. Please provide more info, including what branch is printed in the message and where do you push/pull the current branch.

Answer (score 1):

The answers that suggest `git pull` or `git fetch` are correct.
The message is generated when `git status` sees a difference between `.git/FETCH_HEAD` and `.git/refs/remotes/<repository>/<branch>` (e.g. `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master`).

The latter file records the HEAD from the last fetch (for the repository/branch).  Doing `git fetch` updates both files to the branch's current HEAD.
Of course if there is nothing to fetch (because the local repository is already up-to-date) then `.git/FETCH_HEAD` doesn't change.

Comment: This does not seem to be the case for me: `.git/FETCH_HEAD` contains `9f7336c873ccffc772168bf49807e23ff74014d3                branch 'master' of URL` and `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master` contains `9f7336c873ccffc772168bf49807e23ff74014d3`, yet I still receive the message and neither `git pull` nor `git fetch` solves it

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is a bit old...I was in a similar situation and my answer here helped me fix a similar issue I had

First try with `push -f` or force option

If that did not work it is possible that (as in my case) the remote repositories (or rather the references to remote repositories that show up on `git remote -v`) might not be getting updated.

Outcome of above being your push synced your local/branch with your remote/branch however, the cache in your local repo still shows previous commit (of local/branch ...provided only single commit was pushed) as HEAD.

To confirm the above clone the repo at a different location and try to compare local/branch HEAD and remote/branch HEAD. If they both are same then you are probably facing the issue I did.

Solution:

```
$ git remote -v
github  git@github.com:schacon/hw.git (fetch)
github  git@github.com:schacon/hw.git (push)
$ git remote add origin git://github.com/pjhyett/hw.git
$ git remote -v
github  git@github.com:schacon/hw.git (fetch)
github  git@github.com:schacon/hw.git (push)
origin  git://github.com/pjhyett/hw.git (fetch)
origin  git://github.com/pjhyett/hw.git (push)
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote -v
github  git@github.com:schacon/hw.git (fetch)
github  git@github.com:schacon/hw.git (push)
```

Now do a `push -f` as follows

`git push -f github master` ***### Note your command does not have `origin` anymore!***

Do a `git pull` now
 `git pull github master`

on `git status` receive

`# On branch master`

`nothing to commit (working directory clean)`

I hope this useful for someone as the number of views is so high that searching for this error almost always lists this thread on the top

Also refer [gitref](http://gitref.org/remotes/) for details

Comment: Never do a `push -f` unless you know what you are doing!  At least do a `push --force-with-lease` so that you don't overwrite others' commits!

Answer (score -1):

If you get this message after doing a commit, in order to untrack file in the branch, try making some change in any file and perform commit. Apparently you can't make single commit which includes only untracking previously tracked file.
Finally this post helped me solve whole problem https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/. I just had to remove file from repository history.

Answer (score -1):

Just sharing what happened to me.

I committed a bunch of files and realized there are some files that I dont want to commit, so I used VS code to `undo last commit`, removed the file and added to gitignore, then force-pushed my commit again.

This apparently caused git to think my commit still has to be made to remote, because locally the file was committed somehow.

Solved by `undo last commit` and unstaging the file which is in gitignore now