# git erroneously states I'm ahead of origin/master by 1 commit

Tags: git

[edit: added command outputs as requested, and reorganized for clarity]
I've got two clones of a particular repo checked out.

```
git log
commit e06424b5...
...
commit 557a0eb8...
```

shows the same thing in both, with same hash at the top.

```
git remote show origin
```

same in both

```
git branch
* master
```

still same in both

Now some differences.

From the 'good' clone:

```
git log origin/master..
commit e06424b5...

git show-ref HEAD
e06424b5... refs/remotes/origin/HEAD

# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

From the 'bad' clone:

```
git log origin/master..
commit 557a0eb8...

git show-ref HEAD
557a0eb8... refs/remotes/origin/HEAD

git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
```

This is different [correction: earlier I reported that this output was the same].  show-ref seems to indicate that this checkout is one commit *behind*, while status says it is ahead.  But `git reset --hard e06424b5` changes nothing.

When I ask the 'bad' clone what it thinks needs to be pushed:

```
git diff --stat origin/master
```

it shows the files that were part of the e06424b5 commit, but in fact the only reason this checkout even has those files is because I pulled them.

Anyone know how to make the checkout realize that there's nothing for it to push?

[edit: here are some additional commands and their outputs from the 'bad' clone...]

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline    
* e06424b (HEAD, master)
* 557a0eb (origin/master, origin/HEAD) 

git rev-parse origin/master
557a0eb

git rev-parse HEAD
557a0eb (the previous hash)
e06424b (the correct, most recent hash)
```

Comment: Your comments aren't very clear. Some actual responses from git would be much more helpful then the commands you are giving it... does 'git diff HEAD origin/master' give anything?

Comment: yes, 'git diff HEAD origin/master' shows a large set of diffs, which makes sense because HEAD is pointing to the previous hash, not the latest

Comment: What do you have HEAD set to? when you do 'git branch' what is shown as the current branch?

Comment: Can you please show the output of `git rev-parse origin/master`, `git rev-parse HEAD` on both clones and `git ls-remote origin` from either clone?

Comment: 'git branch' points to master

Comment: on the problem clone: 'git rev-parse origin/master' shows 557a0eb856c... (which is the previous commit hash), and 'git rev-parse HEAD' shows both 557a0eb856c... (the previous hash)
and e06424b5296... (the correct, most recent hash).

On the 'good' clone: rev-parse shows e06424b5296... (the correct, most recent hash) for both origin/master and HEAD

Comment: It looks like you just need to perform a `git fetch` in the first clone, then you can `git merge origin/master`. Or you could `git pull`.

Comment: Yes indeed it looks that way, and yet neither of those fixes it.  Both say everything is already up to date

Comment: `git fetch` doesn't clear this message? I've worked through this issue before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365415/pull-only-repos-git-status-saying-the-branch-is-ahead-of-origin-master-why/7365922#7365922

Comment: It actually just seems like you haven't pushed your changes to the remote branch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your comments, it seems to me that you are actually working in a 'detached head' mode.

The problem, is that your initial post implies that a branch is pointing to a specific place that you don't want it to (This would be much more clear if you actually posted any of the output of the git commands you had run) in which case git reset --hard is what you would expect to do to fix this.

But in fact it seems that HEAD is just pointing to somewhere you expect it to not be, git checkout is the command you use to fix where HEAD is pointing to. I'm assuming that there may be something blocking the checkout from working, which is why I've added --force.

WARNING: using git checkout with the --force parameter may kill any uncommitted changes you have, or things of the like.

```
git checkout --force master
```

Assuming you have a master branch, it's the one you want to checkout, and that it is in fact actually tracking origin/master, this should get you out of the pickle you have found yourself in.

Answer (score 2):

You might have pushed from one of the repos ( the one without the ahead of message). Just because you pushed from one repo, doesn't mean that the other repo will be seeing the same thing. You have to do a `git fetch origin` so the tracking branches are updated.

Answer (score 0):

see the output of

```
git log origin/master HEAD master --graph --decorate --oneline
```

It will show you graphically where each reference is pointing. You can also investigate with

```
gitk master origin/master HEAD
```

Comment: I already know that HEAD is pointing to the wrong place, I just can't make git correct it... reset --hard doesnt seem to have any effect

Comment: you use checkout to move HEAD, git reset changes the current branch. 'git checkout master' to move head to the master branch, or 'git checkout origin/master' to move to the master branch from the origin remote. also you can just do a 'git checkout <Partial Hash' but that might put you into detached head mode, which is probably the situation you are trying to get out of in the first place.

Comment: if you `git status` it should show you "# not on any branch". This means you are headless - not on any branch. But if it says you are ahead of something, it means you are on a branch.