# Git: unable to get remote and local/server the same

Tags: git, gitlab

`git status` on the server returns:

```
On branch develop
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 14 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

My goal is to get the git branch on gitlab.com and on the server synchronized. When I look at the difference between the two, the commits that it states that remote on the server is ahead, are commits I believe are actually there on gitlab.com.

I did the following on the server:

1. `git status` returns "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 14 commits."
2. `git reset --soft HEAD~1`
3. `git status` now returns "branch is up-to-date with origin/develop. Changes to be committed:" and then a list with changes.
4. `git reset --hard`
5. `git status` now returns "branch is up-to-date with origin/develop. Nothing to commit."
6. `git log` is missing the latest commits and therefore essentially disagrees with step 5.
7. `git pull origin develop` This pulls various changes (how is that possible since step 5 returns "up-to-date"...?).
8. `git status` returns the original message "ahead of 'origin/develop' by 14 commits" and I'm back where I started.

I don't understand this. How can the server return to being ahead of gitlab.com (step 8) after pulling from gitlab...? I removed all changes on the server and just did a pull...

Comment: Use `git log origin/develop..` to see the new commits. Yes, with 2 dots.

Comment: If after step 5 I enter `git log origin/develop..`, this returns nothing, not even a blank line...  
And if I do it after step 7, it returns a list of commits that are on gitlab.com, so I don't see why it would consider the server to be ahead these commits in comparison to gitlab.com (after all, it just pulled them from gitlab.com).

Comment: perhaps you forgot to fetch data from remote (as far as I remember git status compare with a local version of the branch)? git fetch -> git pull OR git pull -f (in case of the branch name the same)

Comment: Keep in mind that when `git status` says "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 14 commits", it is not looking at gitlab. It is looking at a _local_ branch, a _tracking_ branch which may not be up to date with what's on gitlab. — Also I'm confused by your statements "`git status` on the server" and "I did the following _on the server_"... really? You gave those commands through ssh or something? Why would you ever do such a thing?

Comment: Thanks for explaining. But then still, how should I synchronize the two?

Comment: Also I don't understand the title, "get origin and remote the same". Origin _is_ the remote.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the title

Comment: But it still doesn't make sense. The local is not the server. The remote, origin, is the server. The local is your computer. That is why I'm asking about your use of the word "server" everywhere. Do you really mean "server" or do you mean the opposite, the "local"?

Comment: So I use gitlab.com, which is the origin. And I have a Linux server, which is what I refer to when using "server". On the server, I would like to do a pull from gitlab.com, and then have `git status` say it's up-to-date.

Comment: And how do you talk to the Linux server? Are you using ssh?

Comment: OK I'm going to suggest that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365415/pull-only-repos-git-status-saying-the-branch-is-ahead-of-origin-master-why.

Comment: What version of Git is installed on this server? I bet it is Git 1.7.1, 1.7.9, or 1.8.1. If that's the case, the problem is that `git pull` is *bypassing the update of `origin/develop`* as it used to do in those ancient versions of Git.

Comment: @torek Yes, that's what I was referring to in the duplicate link I pointed to.

Comment: @matt: that's right, but with Git version 1.8.2 or newer, `git pull origin develop` would actually update `origin/develop` after all. (It would *not* update the other `origin/*` names, which is another reason to avoid `git pull` in favor of a separate`git fetch`... Ah, Git.)

Comment: @torek Yes, thanks for clarifying that even clearer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. git status returns "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 14 commits."

This does not mean that your branch is ahead of the remote (origin). `origin/develop` is a *local* branch. It is a remote tracking branch, but it is not updated automatically. The way to update it is to say `git fetch` — something that you *never* report having said.

> 2. git reset --soft HEAD~1
> 3. git status now returns "branch is up-to-date with origin/develop. Changes to be committed:" and then a list with changes.
> 4. git reset --hard
> 5. git status now returns "branch is up-to-date with origin/develop. Nothing to commit."
> 6. git log is missing the latest commits and therefore essentially disagrees with step 5.

I don't know why you did any of that. You chopped off a bunch of commits from `develop`. Why would you deliberately lame your local branch?

Also, you are wrong about 6: having lamed `develop`, you have caused it to agree with `origin/develop`, which is still sitting there unchanged. They are absolutely in agreement.

> 7. git pull origin develop This pulls various changes (how is that possible since step 5 returns "up-to-date"...?).

It's possible because, once you have lamed `develop`, the remote is ahead of you. So you pull from the remote, and now your `develop` gets the commits from the remote that you just chopped off it.

> 8. git status returns the original message "ahead of 'origin/develop' by 14 commits" and I'm back where I started.

Because you *still* have not updated `origin/develop` by saying `git fetch`.

So basically you've gone around in circles because (a) you don't know what `origin/develop` is and (b) you keep not updating `origin/develop`. Update it! Say `git fetch`, and you will then discover through `git status` what the actual situation is. I suspect that you will find that you are completely up to date and all is well.