# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am getting the following when running `git status`

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
```

I have read on some other post the way to fix this is run `git pull --rebase` but what exactly is rebase, will I lose data or is this simple way to sync with master?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate... This question is asking what does it mean, while the other question is asking how to discard the changes.

Comment: How was this marked as a duplicate by so many people?  The question obviously indicates the person doesn't want to loose their changes.  They've made changes and are confused by the message.  The so-called duplicate question would have the person loose their changes.

Comment: @DerekGreer as soon as I'm finished getting a dupe hammer for Git, I'll start reopening and properly closing questions like this as duplicates of [other Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=Your+branch+is+ahead+of+%27origin%2Fmaster%27).

Comment: I have to say that the question linked to above is not really a duplicate of this question...

Comment: @DerekGreer: how was this marked as a duplicate?  Because most people who mark questions as duplicates don't bother to actually _read and understand_ the question.  If there are superficial similarities, they will jump to the conclusion that the two are identical, and it will be up to the OP or others who are willing to take the time to carefully repeat what should have been obvious in the first place, if the dupe-hunters had actually cared to pay attention.

Comment: ^^^ the practice of which is killing SO, IMO.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432579/git-your-branch-is-ahead-by-x-commits

Comment: late to the party but this might simply mean that your branch is fine and it is ahead of the origin you cloned from and you might not want to update that if it was some template for your django app or something, right..

Answer (score 1240, accepted):

You get that message because you made changes in your local master and you didn't push them to remote. You have several ways to "solve" it and it normally depends on how your workflow looks like:

- In a good workflow your remote copy of master should be the good one while your local copy of master is just a copy of the one in remote. Using this workflow you'll never get this message again.
- If you work in another way and your local changes should be pushed
  then just `git push origin` assuming origin is your remote
- If your local changes are bad then just remove them or reset your
  local master to the state on remote **`git reset --hard origin/main`**

Comment: git reset --hard origin/master is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: @iberbeu you solved my day...git reset --hard origin/master is what I am looking for. +1ed

Comment: Also fwiw `git diff master origin/master` (ie. `git diff local remote`) to see changes you'll be removing

Comment: I have local/master on the remote origin/branch so using `git push origin master:branch` which returned `Everything up-to-date`, after that the message of being ahead by x commits went away.

Comment: Last one got me what I needed there!

Comment: I am kind of having the same issue. But the thing is I tried pushing local commits to the origin using `git push origin master` and after that when I run  `git status` I am still getting the same output saying that `Your branch is ahead of 'remote-branch-name/master' by <some-number> commits.`

Comment: It turned out that I had two target names pointing to the same remote url (origin and the one created from the IDE) and when I push to the origin the IDE says that the `IDE-created-target/master` is behind.

Comment: Anyone trying this answer should be aware that origin/master is not necessarily the branch you want to reset to..........

Comment: git reset --hard origin/master did it for me! --hard HEAD~ wasn't bringing the project inline with the remote!

Comment: $ git push origin master
remote: Forbidden
fatal: unable to access 'https://rajkanase11@bitbucket.org/hrishiawari/electron.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403     .......getting above error while pushing the code

Comment: `git reset --hard origin/master` will delete your changes that you tried to push, but how to preserve them?

Comment: Also _also_ fwiw `git log origin/master..master` is useful to see the commit logs that have not yet been pushed.

Comment: I had the same issue 'git reset --hard origin/master' is helped me)

Comment: The question was for "master", not "main".

Comment: `git push origin` was what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 68):

### Use these 4 simple commands

**Step 1** : `git checkout <branch_name>`

This is obvious to go into that branch.

**Step 2**  : `git pull -s recursive -X theirs`

Take remote branch changes and replace with their changes if conflict arise.
Here if you do `git status` you will get something like this **your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.**

**Step 3**  : `git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>`

**Step 4**  : `git fetch`

Hard reset your branch.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 49):

There is nothing to fix. You simply have made 3 commits and haven't moved them to the remote branch yet. There are several options, depending on what you want to do:

- `git push`: move your changes to the remote (this might get rejected if there are already other changes on the remote)
- do nothing and keep coding, sync another day
- `git pull`: get the changes (if any) from the remote and merge them into your changes
- `git pull --rebase`: as above, but try to redo your commits on top of the remote changes

You are in a classical situation (although usually you wouldn't commit a lot on master in most workflows). Here is what I would normally do: Review my changes. Maybe do a `git rebase --interactive` to do some cosmetics on them, drop the ones that suck, reorder them to make them more logical. Now move them to the remote with `git push`. If this gets rejected because my local branch is not up to date: `git pull --rebase` to redo my work on top of the most recent changes and `git push` again.

Comment: I used git pull --rebase, but it now says I am ahead by one commit

Comment: So I made the changes, pushed to master, and then our team lead merged to master.  So the changes are there I just need to get synced with the current master.

Comment: @MartyMcFly It's hard to see what is going on here. You say you already pushed? So why do you still commits that aren't on master? What do you mean by `your team lead merged to master`? Didn't you say you pushed to master already? What does the extra commit contain? Try `git diff origin/master` to see how your local branch differs from the remote.

Comment: thanks for the help, sorry if I did a bad job explaining the situation.  But what I was looking for is git reset --hard origin/master.  But your answer was helpful +1.

Comment: I seem to be stuck between a rock and a hard place, I tried to commit changes, then git said: you are ahead 11 commits. I am not allowed to update the remote repository, so a push is not possible. "git pull" says: Already up-to-date. So I tried your third suggestion, but then git says: cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes. please commit or stash them. Duh, that's how I got here in the first place :-(

Comment: I had committed changes to my master then deleted my branch and I wasn't sure how to get the changes to the remote since I deleted my branch. "git push" by itself defaults to local and pushed my changes to the remote master.

Comment: If git status reveals no local changes to save, you may have committed but not pushed, Uncommit the last commit to see what's changed by doing: "git reset --soft HEAD~1", then run the later twice more. You can then "git commit & git push" or "git stash" to forget about them.

Answer (score 29):

Came across this issue after I merged a pull request on Bitbucket.

Had to do

```
git fetch
```

and that was it.

Comment: I was working with a repo from a bundle and was able to get rid of the message by applying "git fetch" to a current bundle. tnx!

Comment: On a read-only checkout my git status showed I was 2 commits ahead, the log looked as it should - all commits in the origin. I did a git pull and was 5 commits ahead..WTF???? Just needed to fetch to refresh local indexes...all good :)

Answer (score 24):

If your git says you are commit ahead then just 
First,

> git push origin

To make sure u have pushed all ur latest work in repo

Then,

> git reset --hard origin/master

To reset and match up with the repo

Comment: git push origin worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Usually if I have to check which are the commits that differ from the master I do:

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

In this way I can see the commits and decide to drop it or pick...

Comment: This lowly answer all the way down here was what I needed to do. I couldn't figure out how to find out the difference, and all my various `git diff ...` magicks wouldn't work. When I did this, it gave me `noop` as the only commit, and when I accepted it, now my branch is in-sync with origin/master. So it appears the commits diff from origin/master were in effect nothing.

Answer (score 11):

This message from `git` means that you have made three commits in your local repo, and have not published them to the `master` repository. The command to run for that is `git push {local branch name} {remote branch name}`.

The command `git pull` (and `git pull --rebase`) are for the other situation when there are commit on the remote repo that you don't have in your local repo. The `--rebase` option means that `git` will move your local commit aside, synchronise with the remote repo, and then try to apply your three commit from the new state. It may fail if there is conflict, but then you'll be prompted to resolve them. You can also abort the `rebase` if you don't know how to resolve the conflicts by using `git rebase --abort` and you'll get back to the state before running `git pull --rebase`.

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me once after I merged a pull request on Bitbucket.

I just had to do:

`git fetch`

My problem was solved. I hope this helps!!!

Comment: duplicated from [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40880736/2405914)

Answer (score 7):

> `git reset --hard origin/master`

Use this command

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I used 'git reset --hard origin/master' without quotes to rebase my local master to the remote master branch.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, you have local changes that you committed but didn't push.

If you're unsure about which changes are there, and you want to check before doing a push, the command below will tell you which files changed:

> git diff --stat origin/master..

And if you remove `--stat`, it will show the diff of all files.