# Can't push CSS changes to origin/master.. Everything up-to-date

Tags: git, github, push, git-commit

I am baffled. I made a branch to make css changes to my Ruby on Rails app. Let's call the branch `Update_CSS`After I made changes, I did `git status`and it showed that the css files were not added so I added them with `git add app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`Then I committed my changes with `git commit -am "Updated CSS"`. Then I checked out master and merged branch with CSS changes:

```
git checkout Master
git merge Update_CSS
```

Terminal said changes were merged, blah blah. Then tried to push to git: `git push`. Then I got the following message `Everything up-to-date`! What?! Sure enough, I looked on Github and the the CSS file was different from the one on my machine. I actually have a couple of CSS files that are merged and committed on my machine and not on origin/master. Any idea what's going on or how to fix this. Ideally, I'd like to override the file in origin/master with the one on my local master.

**Update:** When I ran `git checkout master` with a small "m", the output read: `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 9 commits.` I wonder if I was careless with the capitalization of "master" and that somehow screwed things up. I tried changing other files on Master, committing changes, and pushing to git, and now I always get that `Everything up-to-date`.

Comment: As an ad hoc solution when I have encountered a similiar problem problem I make a meaningless change to code, say adding a blank line to controller, and then commit and push.  Also if pushing to Heroku you need to "rake assets:clobber" and "rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace" first before pushing.

Comment: what does a  "git log --graph" tell you?

Comment: This might not be super accurate since I've tried a couple of other things, but the output to git log --graph was:`16:44:16-sergio~/Desktop/Code/atma (Master)$ git log --graph
* commit bb18dd6df6507b2bbd511baf68e1373a25d262f3
| Author: Sergio Paluch <sergiopaluch@gmail.com>
| Date:   Wed Apr 9 16:33:04 2014 -0700
| 
|     Got rid of junk in application.css
|    
*   commit 2b85367175198f4934ee48b0028cfb18be45110e
|\  Merge: e3e129f 422facc
| | Author: Sergio Paluch <sergiopaluch@gmail.com>
| | Date:   Wed Apr 9 16:29:51 2014 -0700
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'Make_Span_Viewport' into Master`

Comment: cont..`| * commit 422facce779e36828db9b073f563816dab4f4788
| | Author: Sergio Paluch <sergiopaluch@gmail.com>
| | Date:   Wed Apr 9 16:29:04 2014 -0700
| | 
| |     Got rid of junk in application.css
| |   
* | commit e3e129f9be38325d8e864c2ef553f034107293c7
|/  Author: Sergio Paluch <sergiopaluch@gmail.com>
|   Date:   Wed Apr 9 16:22:16 2014 -0700
|`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Chris! I actually tried making a meaningless edit to commit again. Basically, followed the same workflow as before. All the commits went through fine on my machine, but when I tried to push to origin/master I keep getting "Everything up-to-date". I didn't know about the `rake assets:precompile` for Heroku, so thanks for that!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really quite sure how it happened, but when I checked out master to merge my branch, I typed "Master" with a capital m. Rather than merging with master, I merged with Master. My solution was to make the updated to master and reset my local branch with `git reset --hard origin/master` as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288176/your-branch-is-ahead-of-origin-master-by-3-commits.)

I'd love to hear what actually happened here in detail because I'm not sure I fully get it. Thanks!

Comment: case sensitivity of branch names was your culprit here