# git repository is 13 commits ahead opencv:master

Tags: git, github

I have just done

```
git pull upstream master -f
```

and my [repo](https://github.com/LaurentBerger/opencv_contrib) is still 13 commits ahead opencv:master.

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432579/git-your-branch-is-ahead-by-x-commits) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288176/your-branch-is-ahead-of-origin-master-by-3-commits) but unfortunately it does not help me.
If i press compare in github interface I can see this 13 commits. How can I have repo even with opencv:master. ?

Thanks for yours answers

Comment: Well your branch **is** [ahead of 13 commits](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/compare/master...LaurentBerger:master). All 13 are commits done by you in your fork and not submitted to the upstream repo. Submit a pull request if you want upstream to have your changes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does it mean a git reset HEAD ~13 and a new git pull upstream will solve my problem

Comment: I try :git reset --hard upstream/master result is HEAD is now at dd9b2eb Merge pull request #710 from VladX:optflow and after git push : ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/LaurentBerger/opencv_contrib'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind