# Master branch is "Already up-to-date", and yet it is "ahead of origin/master by 4 commits"?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-pull, git-checkout

I understand that if I have commits on my local `master` branch that are not in the remote `master` branch, then I can get "Your branch is ahead of origin/master by X commits".

But, after I `git pull origin master`, I see the message "Already up-to-date".  So, I thought that means exactly that:  none of my commits are ahead/behind master.

But when I do `git status` *still* am receiving this message "Your branch is ahead of origin/master by X commits".  Even when I do `git pull -f origin master` I'm *still* getting this message!! How is that possible when I'm "Already up-to-date"?

I understand questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288176/your-branch-is-ahead-of-origin-master-by-3-commits), but they still don't tell me why the "up-to-date" means "ahead"?

Comment: You are ahead of remote branch as long as you won't push to that branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s illustrate by below graphs:

Assume this is the remote master branch,

```
A---B---C origin/master
```

And this is your local master branch, you make X commits on local,

```
A---B---C---D---E---…---N master
```

So when you want to pull remote master branch(commit A,B and C) to local which already exist in local commits, so git will show `already up-to-date message` for you. And this is consistent with git status’ messge `Your branch is ahead of origin/master by X commits`.

Comment: Okay, so "ahead" just means ahead chronologically in terms of commits?

Comment: Yes, ahead means the commits X which you added locally.

Comment: @Candic3: think of it not so much "chronologically" as "topologically", because it's not *time*-based but *location*-based. You are ahead because *you* are ahead. If I also wrote back to the shared repository on your `origin` and *I* got ahead of that `origin` and then *I* pushed to it and *got there first*, I would have my commits on `origin` (they would now be ahead of you by *my* commits) and you would have your commits not yet on `origin` (so you are *also* ahead of `origin`). But if I win this push "race", it's now up to you to collect those commits and figure out how to integrate them.