# What does it mean when one branch is ahead of another?

Tags: git, azure-devops, cicd

I am testing a scenario where devs create feature branches and push them into a dev branch (which is my compare branch). Once per week, we then merge dev into main, which triggers our CI/CD pipeline.

My intention was that main and dev should always match up. However, currently main is showing ahead of dev.

We don't work out of or push to our main branch, so how would it be ahead of our compare branch?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288176/your-branch-is-ahead-of-origin-master-by-3-commits)

Comment: Not really because we didn't make any changes in our main branch. That's not the branch we work out of or push to. This is what's causing my confusion.

Comment: To your side note... yes. And when it didn't match up, that's what started me on my road of confusion.

Comment: You are also right about the word syntax I was using. I've updated my original post.

Comment: I would just look at the 1 commit on `main` to see what it is. If it's 1 ahead before you merge `dev` into `main`, then someone added a commit to `main` on the side (for example, a hotfix, or maybe the pipeline running on `main` makes a commit). If `dev` was fully up to date with `main` before the merge, and then after the merge `main` gets a new commit, then that's because you did a merge that creates a merge commit, even if one wasn't necessary. BTW, the default merge type in AzDO (and many popular tools) does create a merge commit, so if you used that then that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure DevOps, there are [4 merge types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/complete-pull-requests?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#tabpanel_2_browser) to choose from:

1. **Merge (no fast forward)**: Merge with a non-linear history that preserves all commits.
2. **Squash commit**: Merge with a linear history that combines all source commits into a single commit on the target, or squash merges the PR. Be aware that a new commit will be created for the target branch without keeping the commit history from the source branch.
3. **Rebase and fast-forward**: Rebase the source commits onto the target and fast-forward.
4. **Semi-linear merge**: Rebase source commits onto the target and create a two-parent merge.

When your **source** branch is a **shared** branch, such as `dev` or `main`, (usually) the only sensible option to use is #1, "Merge", and in this case you will be creating a new merge commit on `main` when completing a Pull Request from `dev` into `main`.

Given that, you have a few options that you can consider:

1. If for some reason you really don't want to see the merge commit on `main`, you could theoretically avoid it by selecting merge type #3 (rebase and fast-forward). This is slightly dangerous though because if `dev` isn't fully up to date with `main` at the time of the merge, then `dev` will get re-rewritten. If it is fully up to date, it won't touch `dev` and you'll effectively do a merge with fast-forward (if possible, and it would by definition be possible).<sup>1</sup>
2. Allow, the merge commit, and then immediately afterwards merge `main` back into `dev` with a regular merge. Now `dev` would be 1 commit ahead of `main` instead, but this is fine since the norm for your workflow is for `dev` to be ahead of `main` anyway. Note that if you ever have a hotfix into `main`, you'd need to also merge `main` back down to `dev`, so the rule here is something like "Anytime new commits appear on `main`, merge them back down into `dev`."
3. You could setup a pipeline job that does the merge of `dev` into `main` for you. It could be setup to do a fast-forward merge into `main`, and then push it out when it's finished. (Assuming you've protected `main`, you'll also need to give the account that runs the pipeline permission to bypass pull requests.)

---

<sup>1</sup> In AzDO Server, I've seen semi-linear merge fail to even attempt a rebase when more than 25 commits would be rebased. It wouldn't surprise me if that's also true for rebase and fast-forward, however, someone should check whether the number of commits matters when a rebase isn't necessary. If you can't have more than 25 commits regardless of whether a rebase is necessary or not, then this may sometimes thwart the idea to do a fast-forward type merge by cheating with option 3.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have merge commit. Your branches will have equal contents. But if you merge `dev`->`master` you always create one additional merge commit.