# What is the difference between these `git fetch` syntaxes?

Tags: git, syntax, fetch

I've bare-cloned a repository (`git clone --bare`) and apparently `git fetch` doesn't update it, but `git fetch origin master:master` does. I don't understand all the nuances between these syntaxes:

- `git fetch`
- `git fetch origin`
- `git fetch origin master`
- `git fetch origin master:master`

`origin` is my only remote and `master` is my only branch, and the help says:

> When no remote is specified, by default the origin remote will be used

So why these four lines aren't the same?

**Edit:** the three first commands seems to fetch in a temporary branch called `FEATCH_HEAD`. But since I'm using a bare clone, I can't use `git merge` to get the fetched results.

**Edit2:** From @torek's answer, I made a small test and diff'ed a --bare and a --mirror clone directories. Here is the result:

```
diff -ru mesa.bare.git/config mesa.mirror.git/config
--- mesa.bare.git/config    2014-10-14 20:01:42.812226509 -0400
+++ mesa.mirror.git/config  2014-10-14 20:00:53.994985222 -0400
@@ -4,3 +4,5 @@
    bare = true
 [remote "origin"]
    url = git://anongit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa
+   fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
+   mirror = true
Only in mesa.bare.git/objects/pack: pack-17005b7e1020d291eb86d778a174ecf0d60d92a9.idx
Only in mesa.bare.git/objects/pack: pack-17005b7e1020d291eb86d778a174ecf0d60d92a9.pack
Only in mesa.mirror.git/objects/pack: pack-c08b44b7f290ef0bc9abe3a0b974695c85a69342.idx
Only in mesa.mirror.git/objects/pack: pack-c08b44b7f290ef0bc9abe3a0b974695c85a69342.pack
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html ? If so, please edit the question to clarify what wasn't clear after reading it (if anything). Otherwise, please answer the question yourself (and post the answer here)!

Comment: Of course I've read it, otherwise how could I quote a sentence from `git help fetch`?

Comment: normally you would want to have a line like "fetch = refs/heads/*:ref/heads/*" in the origin section of your config, then it will make `git fetch` behave as you expect

Comment: Argh, I should have noticed that you quoted the help. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Andrew C's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350876/what-is-the-difference-between-these-git-fetch-syntaxes#comment41363832_26350876) contains the key here, but I'll expound a bit:

- `git fetch`, with no additional arguments, chooses a remote name by looking at the current branch, or uses `origin` (see the documentation for details).  Having chosen a remote, it then proceeds as for the next form.
- `git fetch remote`, again with no additional arguments, uses the given remote, and extracts the `fetch =` lines for that remote to obtain a set of "refspecs".  It then proceeds similarly to the last case.
- `git fetch remote refspec` uses the given remote and the given refspec (you may give multiple refspecs here) to choose what references to update.

Once `git fetch` has a remote or URL—given the name of a remote, it extracts the `url =` line to obtain the URL—it contacts the other git commands on the remote server and asks them for a list of all of the remote repository's references (branches, tags, and other references, all in the `refs/*` name-spaces, with a special addition for `HEAD` which is also obtainable but not generally used here—it's there for the initial clone step).

For each reference thus obtained, `git fetch` sees whether you have asked it to bring that reference over, and if so, what name you asked git to use in *your* repository.

Again, the names *available* are obtained from the remote.  The names *wanted* are obtained from your refspecs, and the names they will be given in your repository are also obtained from your refspecs.

A refspec of the form `a:b` means "take reference `a`, but call it `b` locally."

A refspec missing the `b` part means "take reference `a`, but put it into the special `FETCH_HEAD` file."  (`FETCH_HEAD` then becomes like a normal reference, like `MERGE_HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD` and so on, except that it has some extra text written to it meant for the `pull` script, so it only sometimes works the way you might expect.)

A refspec may contain a wildcard character: `refs/heads/*` means "take all branches" (branches being, by definition, references that begin with `refs/heads/`).  Normally the `fetch =` line in your git configuration says `refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.<sup>1</sup>  As before, this means to rename the matched branch, with the `*` on the right expanding to whatever the `*` on the left of the colon matched.  So this brings all branches over, but renames them as `origin/master` and the like.  That's normally want you want for a non-`--bare` repository.

Sometimes that's also what you want for a `--bare` repository, and sometimes it's not.  In particular, sometimes you want a "mirror" repository, which is a bare clone that simply slave-copies some other repository.  To change an ordinary bare repository into such a mirror, you simply need to modify the `fetch =` line: instead of `refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` the line should read `fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`.  In fact, you may want to bring over *everything* (tags and even notes) with `fetch = refs/*:refs/*`.  Whether you actually want this is something only you can decide, of course.

Note that this is common enough that `git clone` has a flag to set it up automatically: clone with `--mirror` and you get a bare clone with the modified `fetch =` line.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually the line reads `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, i.e., there is also a leading `+` character.  This plus-sign sets the "force flag", as if you had used `git fetch --force`, for that particular reference-update.  This is not particularly relevant to the spelling issues here, but I'll note that usually you want a forced update for remote branches like the one listed here, and also for pure mirror repositories.

If you're mirroring tags, you probably want those to do forced-update.  Ideally, of course, tags never change (nor are deleted) so in an ideal world this would not matter, but in the real world they do sometimes change, or get deleted.

To handle reference deletion, you must tell `git fetch` to `--prune` (or, similarly, supply `--prune` to `git remote update`).  There is no syntax in refspecs for automatic pruning (although it would be reasonable, I have not seen any proposal for it).

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer!

See the "Edit2".

Comment: Apparently adding `fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` does not work as I expect in my case. Because I also used a `--depth 6000` during the clone, adding this line to my `config` file makes `git fetch` to try to get the entire repository. But if in put `fetch = master:master`, then everything works fine!

Comment: I have never experimented with shallow clones, but presumably when you bring over `refs/heads/*` you're getting a branch that causes git to deepen the repo; but with `master:master` you bring over only `master` (git automatically qualifies this to `refs/heads/master`, on both sides of the refspec) and it stops when it hits a commit that you have, so it will only deepen the clone if you merge a commit that is not already in your 600.