# git restoring from backup misaligned repositories

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm using gitlab server. Due to hardware crash, I had to reinstall everything and restore git repos from backup.

Backup is a bit older.

git status shows:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 9 commits.
```

but this origin/dev is now old, so I've probably 12 commits that are ahead.

Do I simply push? now?

ho do I get it in sync again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, being that your origin is now out of date, you can push to get it back up to date with at least the work you had locally. If you want to see exactly what that work is, you could branch locally and create a MR for it. Or you could run `git diff origin/dev dev` to see what content you are going to push.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what message already try to say `you has some commits ahead from master so please push them`

[more description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2435437/5318264)