# GitHub - Failed to sync this branch

Tags: git, github

I recently added added a commit (some files) to my github repository, but upon trying to sync it I get the 'Failed to sync this branch - you might want to open a shell and debug the state of this repo'. `git push` doesn't appear to do anything (it just gives me a new line without printing any text), and `git status` gives me:

```
 On branch master
 Your branch us ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
      (use "git push" to publish your local commits")
 Nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

[image]
Also, for some reason the github icon disappeared off my desktop (I'm using W7 64) and when I used `where /r C:\ GitHub.exe` I got two results (of the actual EXE), both in my `AppData/Local`. After that, the problems started.

What am I doing terribly wrong?

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432579/git-your-branch-is-ahead-by-x-commits

Comment: That other answer doesn't look very focused. I think all you need to do is `git pull` first, so you can resolve any issues and then push cleanly.

Comment: @ThorSummoner, I tried `git pull` followed by `git push` - no result...

Comment: what message do you get pack when issuing `git push` from the shell?

Comment: @ThorSummoner, I don't get a message, just a new line.

Comment: What if you tried "git push -u origin master" ?

Comment: @AkramFares - I get the same result as if I try `git push`